# Stream RTSP from ONVIF general camera to Youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I have a wifi camera that uses RTSP/ONVIF protocol and after reading FFMPEG docs and some threads at Google I am trying to broadcast the stream to Youtube. So I started a broadcast at youtube and in my computer in ffmpeg I executed this command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://200.193.21.176:6002/onvif1 -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/private_key
```

The command above looks like it's correct cause it ouputs constantly something like this:

[image: log of ffmpeg]

The problem is that at YOUTUBE it still says I am offline. Why?

Comment: Try replace first part to: ffmpeg -re -i somefile.mp4, so you will to know, if here any problems with your camera or not.

Comment: IT WORKED MY FRIEND! I removed "ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://200.193.21.176:6002/onvif1" and replaced by "ffmpeg -re -i teste.mp4" and it worked! So the problem looks like in the RTSP. But if I use VLC (for example) I can access the camera content using "rtsp://200.193.21.176:6002/onvif1" why cant ffmpeg work?

Comment: ffmpeg and VLC very similar and even uses same code for codecs. But RTSP it handles differently. But try just ffmpeg -i rtsp://200.193.21.176:6002/onvif1 and nothing more as source

Comment: Thanks my friend. I tried the simple command you gave me and it shows this "'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required) ". I downloaded ffmpeg from ffmpeg official site and it looks like it was compiled without having pthread enabled... any idea how I could get ffmpeg with pthread enable?

Comment: Build yourself, it easy

Comment: If you add that as an answer I accept it! I gave up using windos and decided to use linux and now I at least made it work but I am having a small problem. Could you please take  a look at -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025921/ffmpeg-displaying-top-of-the-image

Comment: Same as my. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016825/ffmpeg-onvif-to-rtmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace first part to: `ffmpeg -re -i somefile.mp4`, so you will to know, if here any problems with your camera or not.

ffmpeg and VLC very similar and even uses same code for codecs. But RTSP it handles differently. But try just `ffmpeg -i rtsp://200.193.21.176:6002/onvif1` and nothing more as source.