# FFMPEG displaying top of the image

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to get my camera video (using RTSP) and send it to youtube. There are plenty of command lines you can use and this is the one worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://200.193.21.176:6003/onvif1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/fh1t-e7p4-fsa1-c8mw
```

The problem is that it is only displaying correctly the top part of the video, the rest looks like scrumbled. See:

[image]

Maybe I should use some additional parameter to make it render all the video instead of only the top and poorly the rest?

EDIT: there is no prolbem with the video capture cause when I use VLC to see the video from the RTSP it is working perfectly. Here is the image using VLC:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely encoder rtsp stream is not getting feeds at required rate. Check the network. I had the same issue changed camera settings to stream at 1280X720 VBR. then its perfect.
Edit:
1. ALso check the encoders uplink speed. The VLC stream appears its running 1080 Full HD or something which needs lot of upstream data to youtube.

BTW keep your stream key private.... Else you will end up in Jail is someone streams something undesirable to your site.

Comment: Please my friend see edit. Using VLC I can see all the video with no problem.

Comment: Sorry I will keep my stream private I will change it right now! Thanks my friend. Would you mind telling me how do I change the stream to 1280x720 using the command line? Maybe it could work!

Comment: I had exactly same experience, My VLC used to play perfectly which just added another 1 month to debug that issue. Adjust the frame rates to match network upstream speed everything will be perfect. Login to your camera http interface and set the bit-rate and resolution & frames per second. Also check your laptops uplink speed @ speedtest.net.

Comment: I never player with ffmpeg, this is my first time! I have no idea how to do that. If you could only tell me the parameter that I should add to the comand line I will try several frame rates till I get one that works.

Comment: try play with ffplay: ffplay rtsp://your_url

Answer (score 0):

Try to add rtsp_transport option:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://200.193.21.176:6003/onvif1 ...
```

Or just play:

```
ffplay rtsp://200.193.21.176:6003/onvif1
```

Comment: I tried adding rtsp_transport and it shows no error message but the same behaviour happens.